# Take oldest record in a set of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, min

So, I have this problem, I have this set of records in a table

| TemperatureID | CastingID | TemperatureDateTime | TemperatureValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1421294 | 1073513 | 2021-01-07 11:53:00.000 | 1648 |
| 1421295 | 1073513 | 2021-01-07 11:54:00.000 | 1698 |
| 1421326 | 1073514 | 2021-01-07 22:00:00.000 | 1594 |
| 1421327 | 1073514 | 2021-01-07 22:11:00.000 | 1609 |

and this repeated many times.
My problem is that I have to take only the oldest record for each set of CastingID just like that:

| TemperatureID | CastingID | TemperatureDateTime | TemperatureValue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1421294 | 1073513 | **2021-01-07 11:53:00.000** | 1648 |
| 1421326 | 1073514 | **2021-01-07 22:00:00.000** | 1594 |

I tried using DISTINCT and MIN functions, but I can't obtain the result I want, can you please help me or provide some examples?

Comment: use [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I tried using this query but it just returns the entire set without filtering:          `select  top 100 t.CastingID, t.TemperatureValue, t.TemperatureDate 
from (select CastingID, TemperatureValue, MIN(TemperatureDateTime) as TemperatureDate from production.Temperatures WHERE YEAR(TemperatureDateTime) = 2021 
   group by CastingID, TemperatureValue) t
 order by CastingID`

Comment: @Squirrel hi thanks for your suggestion, together with the answer below it resolved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *
        , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CastingID ORDER BY TemperatureDateTime ASC) RN
    FROM TABLE_1
) A
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer I had to modify it a bit by using row_number as suggested by @Squirrel above but it works like a charm I dare say.